# Simulating Sand in Blender

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to make an hourglass in blender using the Molecular add-on, but I can't seem to get the settings right. Either the particles go through the hole without building up as it would in a normal hourglass, or they have a spring effect. What would be some good settings to use for sand simulation? Additionally, I'm having trouble actually simulating with a 3700x and 16GB. The memory usage goes very high and the time per frame seems to exponentially grow. Can someone please recommend some good settings to simulate sand?

Please remember that I'm just a beginner, and have only been using Blender and Molecular very recently.

Comment: Havent done it in  quite a while but emulating sand is heavy computational, molecular is computational. If you dont want to waste time mabe try other areas of blender.
If you still want to go on take a good video tut first like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYjLh1M78eA

Comment: In Blender 3.1 Cycles can now render point clouds with geometry nodes. The mantaflow liquid simulation can be used to create sand as shown here: https://youtu.be/MjM16FUMOKM